# Why append class 'fa' in front of all font-awesome icon?

Tags: font-awesome

I have seen font-awesome icons have the class 'fa' for all icons like this:

```
<i class='fa fa-snapchat-ghost'></i>
```

Why not simply

```
<i class='fa-snapchat-ghost'></i>
```

? What does the class `fa` give you?

Comment: Why not have a look into the [font-awesome.css](http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css)?

Answer (score 1):

Its a matter of efficiency within the CSS file that jmoerdyk linked to...

adding an `@extend .fa` directive into each and every icon would:

a) run counter to what CSS is based on from a theoretical standpoint.

b) add way more lines of code than simply having a single class assign properties that every icon needs in order to render correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's no different than why Bootstrap (or any other framework) relies on multiple CSS tags; efficiency of code and avoiding redundancy.  Consider:

1. All Font Awesome icons need to use the Font Awesome Font.
2. They must all have the same `display` as well as other CSS styles
   applied

Without `.fa` every icon would need to repeat those styles, adding unnecessary bloat to code and increasing the possibility that discrepancies might occur as new icons are added.

The overall size of the CSS file (even minified) would be larger due to repetition, so there is that concern as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what `.fa` gives:

```
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

So in addition to the icon you show, this style also gets applied.

Check the full [source code](http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css)